# using awk to print login stats to a file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am using awk to put server login's in a new file. I only need the first 10 login's along with fields 1, 5, 6 of a past user. This is the awk command I am issuing but I am getting the entire server login stats of everyone placed in the new file I have created. Note the name "mark" is the example last name of the person I want to check:

```
awk -F: '(NR > 1 && NR < 11)  {print $1, $5, $6}' last mark > name_list
```

Comment: What is the 'last' in the command?  If you can provide a sample file, it will be of help for us.

Comment: The last command just echo's out to the screen a list of a particular user's login's to a server. I just want to capture and print to a file the last 10 login's w/ fields 1, 5, & 6. Just FYI mark is the example person's last name.

Comment: As written, this is telling `awk` to try to read two files, one named `last` and another named `mark`. I'm pretty sure this isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (I hope I understand your needs & that your `last` command output the same as mine) :

```
last | awk 'NR<=10{print $1, $5, $6}' > name_list
```

And if you'd like to create a new file for any users :

```
last | awk 'NR<=10{print $1, $5, $6 > $1".txt"}'
```

Comment: Great! I have used this format and even modified it to do other things for my files. Can't thank you enough. Cheers.

Comment: The more common way of doing it is awk '{do stuff} NR==10{exit}' so you don't keep parsing the input long after you've got all the output you want. Won't make a noticable difference for small files though.